# How to Service Objects in Subfolders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have many service objects in my service folder. I'm using Rails 4:

```
 ->services
   a_gen.rb
   b_gen.rb
   ...
   a_pro.rb
   b_pro.rb
   ...
```

I would like my folder structure to be something like

```
  ->services
    ->gen
       a_gen.rb
       b_gen.rb
       ...
    ->pro
       a_pro.rb
       b_pro.rb
       ...
```

I tried just making the folders and putting the objects there, but Rails complains about not able to find it. Do I have to tell rails to look there?

Update:

I am getting this error:

NameError - uninitialized constant ExampleModelName::APro

Even with the path loaded. Once it is in the subfolder.. Rails is looking into the wrong place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that in two ways.

If you want `rails` to autoload them without you making any modifications to the `config.autoload_paths`, define your classes per the folder structure as follows:

```
module Gen
  class ServiceA
  end
end
```

If you don't want to make any changes to your class definition, then you could add those sub folders to the `config.autoload_paths` as follows in your `config/application.rb`

```
module YourApplication
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += [
      "#{Rails.root}/app/services/gen",
      "#{Rails.root}/app/services/prod"
    ]
  end
end
```

Comment: Which would be the better approach?

Comment: It boils down to personal choice. Most of the time, I have seen 2nd approach is being used more often than 1st approach, as you don't need to keep updating your classes when the folder structure changes.

Comment: Does this still work for Rails 5?   It doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: For those coming from a OOP PHP background, the former is much much like namespacing your classes out. Plus you get the bonus of being able to dynamically grab all of your classes in a module, which is pretty amazing. It really helps "modularize" your code, which in PHP you'd have to do with some kind of registry pattern.

Answer (score 3):

for a recursive solution

```
# application.rb
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/services/**/"]
```

Comment: Does this try to add non folders to the path as well?

Comment: it adds all files under `app/services` as well as any files under any subfolders in `app/services`; http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do. In `config/application.rb`, you can add the subfolders to the `config.autoload_paths` collection.

Comment: Can you give an example, I tried that and it does not work

Comment: I tried config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/services/gen)